# Apache SimpleXML loaded but PHP can't access

Tags: php, apache, magento, module, simplexml

I have magento installed on my Centos 6 Apache 2.4 , Easy Apache 4, PHP7 server.

Since yesterday I am having an issue that the function simplexml_load_string cannot be found.

When i run php -m in SSH i can see SimpleXML in the list of modules.

However if I check get_loaded_extensions() it does not show up in the array?

I tried reinstalling via

yum install ea-php70-xml-simplexml

but it said its up to date and already installed.

I dont know what to do know:( how can the module be loaded in php somehow not available again?

Comment: You sure that site is set to use PHP 7?  Check your phpinfo and see what version you're running

Comment: Your CLI and apache PHP versions can differ. Run apache and have it output the version it is running.

Comment: its running php7, confirmed in phpinfo() and in php -v

Comment: @chris85 any idea how i can add simplexml to the apache version too?